# What CMS from 2004 uses the files /shop, /shop/shopper_lookup.asp, and /shop/products.asp

Tags: cms, asp

Background: I've been asked to review a site for a client who has just purchased another business. The old site needs to have a total rebuild, but some of the combinations make me wonder about which technologies were used. This one is digging back to 2004.

I don't have access to the files yet, but the pages are are .asp. The structure of the directories is /shop, /shop/shopper_lookup.asp, /shop/products.asp, etc. . Does that ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: Are you trying to work out what was used to build it e.g. a CMS or shopping cart?  If it is .asp and dates back to 2004 I suggest it was custom built.

Comment: It can't be very popular, only a couple sites have `/shop/shopper_lookup.asp` [in their URLs](https://www.google.com/#q=inurl:/shop/shopper_lookup.asp&*)

Comment: Something in the back of my head says that I have seen this structure before, but I can't pull up what the circumstances or the site were. But the fact that I had seen that directory structure made me consider whether it was some kind of early CMS or shopping cart. So, I thought I would ask in case the new business owner can dig up the original. There may be some images stored that we need to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Stephen Ostermiller's research I looked at one of the sites and note that at the bottom of the source code it says

```
<!-- Web Site Created with Microsoft Site Server Commerce Edition 3.0 Site Builder Wizard -->
```

But neither have matching URLS for registering, but it is something to investigate.

Comment: Oh snap! I used to write code for this years and years ago. What a piece of dog squeeze! Far more work than necessary. I would bang something solid out in 1 or 2 weeks using PERL and it would take months using site server. Run away. Do not walk. Run! ;-) BT rejected it for their commercial e-commerce product and found it far more efficient to write something from scratch using Oracle, Java, JavaScript, etc. We had lots of resources and found that Site Server was a waste of time.

Comment: Jackpot! Also using Stephen Ostermiller's research, one of the sites uses not only the same file structure but the same visual template: http://www.designermoulding.com. And, both the site linked here and the site I have in question are in the building construction industry. 

This is like shaking the haystack and having two needles drop out at your feet. I bet there are more of them.